# Multiline sed in Makefile

Tags: sed, make

I have a `sed` command that I want to use in a `Makefile`. It works in the terminal. The command is

```
sed -n '/[{]/,/[}]/{
p
/[}]/a\
 //end of block matching brace
}' myfile.txt
```

This results in these error messages from `make`:

```
/bin/sh: 2: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string
```

If I add backslashes or place everything on one line I get

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 14: extra characters after command
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does it work if you escape all newlines _and_ the ``\`` that occurs at the end of one of the lines, so that you have ``a\\\`` on that line?

Comment: Won't `awk '/[{]/,/[}]/{print; if($0~/[}]/)print "//end of ..."}'` do the same and fit on a single line? There probably are ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but I'm not able to figure out any _standard_ way to do it.

Comment: @Kusalananda No.

Comment: @mosvy Yes, that worked! Thank you so much. I only had to use two dollar signs instead of one.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
$ sed -n -e '/[{]/,/[}]/{p; /[}]/ a\ //end of block matching brace' -e' }' file
{sdfg
If I add backslashes or place everything on one line I get
df }
 //end of block matching brace
```

Be aware of the TWO `-e` (expression) options needed because you need to terminate the append text. Not all `sed` versions allow for append text in the same line (my GNU `sed` does, my FreeBSD `sed` does not).

Comment: For BSD `sed` divide the `a` command up into two expressions, one ending ``a\`` and one beginning `//end`.

Comment: Thank you! This works, but I think I will use @mosvy 's answer, as since its more portable.

Comment: @ Kusalananda: unfortunately, I get an error message with your hint: `sed: 1: "//end of block matching ...": invalid command code e`

Comment: @RudiC Did you forget the `-e`? `sed -n -e '/[{]/,/[}]/{p; /[}]/ a\' -e '//end of block matching brace' -e '}'`

Comment: @Theo mosvy hasn't submitted an answer, but you could use it in a self-answer if you also explained it.

Comment: @ Kusalananda: No, what I ran looked exactly as you said, I even copied your line - same (error) result. The `e` cited there is the one in `end`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the TWO -e (expression) options"? There's only one

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I am struggling with newlines, backslashes esp in  makefiles, I reach for the `G` command in sed. What's more, it allows one to remain within Posix sed:

```
$ sed -e '/[{]/,/[}]/!d' -e '/[}]/G' -e 's|\n|&//end of block matching brace|' myfile.xt
```

Comment: My `sed`-fu isn't as strong as yours... what's special about `G` please?

Comment: One doesn't need to slip in an escaped newline in the RHS of s/// and then the sed expression can be single lined. All this n still posixly.

Answer (score 1):

With gnu make and a shell that accepts `$''` you can use an intermediate variable as make handles `\eol` differently outside recipes:

```
make  -f - <<\!
define mycmd
sed -n $$'/[{]/,/[}]/{\n\
p\n\
/[}]/a\\\n\
 //end of block matching brace\n\
}' myfile.txt
endef

.PHONY: default
default:
        $(mycmd)
!
```

Each line had `\n\` added, and the solitary `\` was doubled. Make converts the `\eol` outside recipes into a space, so it all ends up on one line, then the shell `$''` converts the `\n` into real newlines. You don't have to use `define` to set the variable; `MYCMD = sed...` works similarly.